# Parsing an XML file in PHP

Tags: php, parsexml

I have this piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><testXML><UserId>00077</UserId><FirstName><![CDATA[ Test]]></FirstName><LastName><![CDATA[Test]]></LastName></testXML>
```

obtained by using `urldecode($info)`.

How I can parse this information?

Can I use `simplexml_load_file (urldecode($info))`?

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [`simplexml_load_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) in PHP

```
<?php
$xml='<?xml version="1.0"?><testXML><UserId>00077</UserId><FirstName><![CDATA[ Test]]></FirstName><LastName><![CDATA[Test]]></LastName></testXML>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [UserId] => 00077
    [FirstName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [LastName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

If you want to access specific element.. you can do like `echo $xml->UserId;` that prints you `00077` , Also, you can make use of a `foreach` construct to traverse through all the elements

A `foreach` demo

```
foreach($xml as $k=>$v)
{
    echo "$k => $v\n";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
UserId => 00077
FirstName =>  Test
LastName => Test
```

Comment: $xml->FirstName returns ![CDATA[ Test]] ?

Comment: @user880386, Please check the edited answer for that.